# faster random generator on List<int> (specified seeds)

Tags: c#, performance, random, parallel-processing

first the question is about performance: can i make the random generation any faster?, given that: 
i am implementing a .Shuffle() Extension method (found in SO)
though when used properly (i.e., giving little time to regenerate) 
it gets real slow, as my needs are to repeate the genaration in a for loop 
over 1k times on each seed set.

say the 'banks' are

```
List<int> seedLst1 = new List<int>(){2, 4, 6, 8, 10.....}
List<int> seedLst2 = new List<int>(){10, 15, 20, 11, 22, 33.....}
```

so i  call them in as parameter(within a container)

```
List<List<int>> allSeedSetsLst 

//randsPerSet - how many random items in each resultset
//count - total iteration on each of the sorces

List<List<int>> getRandRes(List<List<int>> SeedsBank, int count, int randsperSet)
{
    List<List<int>> RetGuessList = new List<List<int>>();

    foreach (var CurSeedLst in SeedsBank)
    {
        int randomIntrval = 55;
        List<int> curRandSet;
        for (i=0; i < count; i++)
        {
            curRandSet = new List<int>();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(randomInterval * 15);
            curRandSet = CurSeedLst.Shuffle().Take(randsperSet);

            randomInterval = curRandSet.Last();

            RetGuessList.Add(curRandSet);
        }
    }
    return RetGuessList;
}
```

the shuffle code

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.Shuffle(new Random());
}
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (rng == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("rng");

    return source.ShuffleIterator(rng);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> ShuffleIterator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
{
    List<T> buffer = source.ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Count; i++)
    {
        int j = rng.Next(i, buffer.Count);
        yield return buffer[j];

        buffer[j] = buffer[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Want to make it faster, don't use Thread.Sleep and instead solve the root problem that you are using Thread.Sleep to solve.

Comment: `int randomIntrval = 55;` doesn't seem very random to me :)

Comment: @Rob randomInterval = curRandSet.Last();

Comment: That still assumes your input set is evenly distributed random values. Also, what happens when the set contains the value `10,000,000` - It will randomly freeze your application... Anyway, as @ScottChamberlain mentioned before - why are you sleeping at all when you're worried about performance?

Comment: @Rob to avoid repating seeds, when i didn't use sleep, it was repating

Comment: @AviaAfer The shuffle code you're using is fundamentally broken for tight loops. (At least the top method). Create a new `Random` object at the start of your method (or better yet - a private variable), and pass it into the shuffle method

Comment: @AviaAfer then use a random class to generated seeds for other random classes.

Comment: @Eser can you give an example please? , how will it effect the performance givent that without the sleep it repeats

Comment: why not generate random numbers like this ? [C# in depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx)

Comment: AviaAfer @Rob's suggetion is better. Use it.

Comment: Are you sleeping to get a new random seed with each iteration? If so, don't! This algorithm is utterly broken and you will definitely not have anything random. Allocate one and only one Random instance, and remove any sleep to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Thread.Sleep` to keep Random from repeating, you already have a extension that takes in a `Random` use a single instance and use that instead, in fact copy the pattern, have one overload that takes in a `Random` and one that makes a new one.

```
List<List<int>> getRandRes(List<List<int>> SeedsBank, int count, int randsperSet)
{
    return getRandRes(SeedsBank, count, randsperSet, new Random());
}

List<List<int>> getRandRes(List<List<int>> SeedsBank, int count, int randsperSet, Random rand)
{
    List<List<int>> RetGuessList = new List<List<int>>();

    foreach (var CurSeedLst in SeedsBank)
    {
        for (i=0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var curRandSet = CurSeedLst.Shuffle(rand).Take(randsperSet).ToList();    
            RetGuessList.Add(curRandSet);
        }
    }
    return RetGuessList;
}
```

Now each call to `Shuffle` will use the same `Random` object instead of needing to create a new one, this gets rid of the need for the random `Thread.Sleep` calls.

---

**P.S.:** You are not following C#'s standard [capitalization conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx). The correct way would be (plus a few other tweaks)

```
List<List<int>> GetRandRes(List<List<int>> seedsBank, int count, int randsperSet, Random rand)
{
    var retGuessList = new List<List<int>>(seedsBank.Count * count);

    foreach (var curSeedLst in seedsBank)
    {
        for (i=0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var curRandSet = curSeedLst.Shuffle(rand).Take(randsperSet).ToList();    
            retGuessList.Add(curRandSet);
        }
    }
    return retGuessList;
}
```

Comment: scott thanks for the correct && well explained answer ! (: